# My RF wireless keyboard keeps sending XF86Forward KeyPress and KeyRelease events to the system after each keypress/keyrelease I do

Tags: linux, keyboard

After one fall, my RF wireless keyboard keeps sending XF86Forward KeyPress and KeyRelease events to the system after each keypress/keyrelease I do :

```
$ xev -event keyboard | egrep -w "KeyPress|KeyRelease|keycode"
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 24 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 24 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event, serial 311, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 56 (keysym 0x62, b), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event, serial 312, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event, serial 312, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 56 (keysym 0x62, b), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event, serial 313, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event, serial 313, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event, serial 313, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event, serial 314, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event, serial 315, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event, serial 315, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
KeyPress event, serial 315, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event, serial 316, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
KeyRelease event, serial 317, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
```

Because of this, I'm unable to log on to my tty[1-6] consoles because each character I type gets a `^@` character appended to it :

```
$ showkey -k
 kb mode was UNICODE
 [ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
 since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

 press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
 keycode  28 release
 keycode  16 press
 keycode 159 press
 keycode  16 release
 keycode 159 release
 keycode  48 press
 keycode 159 press
 keycode  48 release
 keycode 159 release
 keycode  46 press
 keycode 159 press
 keycode  46 release
 keycode 159 release
 keycode  32 press
 keycode 159 press
 keycode  32 release
 keycode 159 release
```

EDIT0 : According to `/proc/bus/input/devices` I have 2 `/dev/input/eventX` entries for my RAPOO wireless keyboard+mouse combo :

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices  | grep -P '^[NH]: ' | paste - - | grep RAPOO
N: Name="RAPOO RAPOO 5G Wireless Device"    H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event2 leds 
N: Name="RAPOO RAPOO 5G Wireless Device"    H: Handlers=kbd mouse0 event3
```

Seems logical because the mouse uses the same RF channel as the keyboard to communicate with the USB mini-receiver.

EDIT1 : According to the Handlers value above `/dev/input/event2` seems to receive events from the keyboard alone.
Here's an `evtest` output for `/dev/input/event2` :

```
$ sudo evtest /dev/input/event2
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x24ae product 0x2003 version 0x110
Input device name: "RAPOO RAPOO 5G Wireless Device"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
...
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML) state 0
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL) state 0
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL) state 0
    Event code 3 (LED_COMPOSE) state 0
    Event code 4 (LED_KANA) state 0
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1625417787.379951, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70058
Event: time 1625417787.379951, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 96 (KEY_KPENTER), value 0
Event: time 1625417787.379951, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625417794.923958, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70004
Event: time 1625417794.923958, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 1
Event: time 1625417794.923958, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
qEvent: time 1625417795.051954, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70004
Event: time 1625417795.051954, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 0
Event: time 1625417795.051954, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625417797.083970, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70005
Event: time 1625417797.083970, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 48 (KEY_B), value 1
Event: time 1625417797.083970, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
bEvent: time 1625417797.187973, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70005
Event: time 1625417797.187973, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 48 (KEY_B), value 0
Event: time 1625417797.187973, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625417798.363970, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70006
Event: time 1625417798.363970, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 46 (KEY_C), value 1
Event: time 1625417798.363970, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
cEvent: time 1625417798.459960, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70006
Event: time 1625417798.459960, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 46 (KEY_C), value 0
Event: time 1625417798.459960, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625417799.195958, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70007
Event: time 1625417799.195958, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 32 (KEY_D), value 1
Event: time 1625417799.195958, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
dEvent: time 1625417799.259976, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70007
Event: time 1625417799.259976, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 32 (KEY_D), value 0
Event: time 1625417799.259976, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625417801.379970, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1625417801.379970, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1625417801.379970, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625417801.587964, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70006
Event: time 1625417801.587964, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 46 (KEY_C), value 1
Event: time 1625417801.587964, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

EDIT2: Whereas `/dev/input/event3` seems to receive events from both the keyboard and the mouse.
Here's an `evtest` output for `/dev/input/event3` (notice the `KEY_FORWARD` events after each keypress and keyrelease) :

```
$ sudo evtest /dev/input/event3
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x24ae product 0x2003 version 0x110
Input device name: "RAPOO RAPOO 5G Wireless Device"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    ...
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 32 (ABS_VOLUME)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      896
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1625418203.492208, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418203.492208, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 0
Event: time 1625418203.492208, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418205.620275, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418205.620275, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 1
Event: time 1625418205.620275, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
aEvent: time 1625418205.908189, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418205.908189, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 0
Event: time 1625418205.908189, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418207.076271, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418207.076271, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 1
Event: time 1625418207.076271, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
bEvent: time 1625418207.348222, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418207.348222, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 0
Event: time 1625418207.348222, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418208.356296, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418208.356296, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 1
Event: time 1625418208.356296, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
cEvent: time 1625418208.660204, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418208.660204, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 0
Event: time 1625418208.660204, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418209.636254, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418209.636254, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 1
Event: time 1625418209.636254, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
dEvent: time 1625418209.924202, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0225
Event: time 1625418209.924202, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 159 (KEY_FORWARD), value 0
Event: time 1625418209.924202, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418211.564204, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90001
Event: time 1625418211.564204, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
Event: time 1625418211.564204, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418211.620212, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90001
Event: time 1625418211.620212, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 0
Event: time 1625418211.620212, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418216.572202, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90002
Event: time 1625418216.572202, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 273 (BTN_RIGHT), value 1
Event: time 1625418216.572202, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418216.644212, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90002
Event: time 1625418216.644212, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 273 (BTN_RIGHT), value 0
Event: time 1625418216.644212, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418218.780207, type 2 (EV_REL), code 0 (REL_X), value -1
Event: time 1625418218.780207, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1625418218.788214, type 2 (EV_REL), code 0 (REL_X), value -1
Event: time 1625418218.788214, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
^C
```

EDIT3: `sudo timeout 5s evtest --grab /dev/input/eventX` works but the pb. is that :

`/dev/input/event2` only receives all `EV_KEY` keyboard events WITHOUT extra `KEY_FORWARD` `EV_KEY` events and no mouse events.
And `/dev/input/event3` seems to receive mouse events and ONLY `KEY_FORWARD` `EV_KEY` keyboard events (no other `EV_KEY` events).

So, I use only `/dev/input/event2`, the mouse will not work and if I use only `/dev/input/event3`, the keyboard will not work.

`udevadm info` confirms that `/dev/input/event2` is used for the keyboard events and `/dev/input/event3` is used for the mouse events:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/input/event2 | grep event-
S: input/by-id/usb-RAPOO_RAPOO_5G_Wireless_Device-event-kbd
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.3-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-RAPOO_RAPOO_5G_Wireless_Device-event-kbd /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.3-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd
$ udevadm info /dev/input/event3 | grep event-
S: input/by-id/usb-RAPOO_RAPOO_5G_Wireless_Device-if01-event-mouse
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.3-usb-0:1:1.1-event-mouse
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.3-usb-0:1:1.1-event-mouse /dev/input/by-id/usb-RAPOO_RAPOO_5G_Wireless_Device-if01-event-mouse
```

How can I stop my RF keyboard from sending those XF86Forward KeyPress and KeyRelease events ?

Comment: replace it ....

Comment: First step is to use `evtest` and see if this also happens on the kernel input layer. Also, RF keyboards sometimes have multiple input devices associated to them (use `evtest` on all of them to verify), so if the `XF86Forward` happens to come from a different device than the actual keypresses, ignoring that device would be an easy fix.

Comment: @dirkt Hi, thank you for suggestion. You will find my commands' outputs in EDIT0, EDIT1 and EDIT2. Can you please have a look ?

Comment: Next step is to use `evtest --grab` on the key+mouse device to make events exclusively go to evtest, so they are not handled by X or the vt's. With vt's, this may be a bit tricky, because I don't know if switching vt's will keep the grab or not. Also have a look at `/dev/input/by-*` to identify the devices correctly across boots. If this works, you can try to launch an `evtest --grab /dev/input/... > /dev/null` or similar during boot.

Comment: @dirkt See my EDIT3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's sum up:

First step is to use `evtest` and see if this also happens on the kernel input layer. Also, RF keyboards sometimes have multiple input devices associated to them (use `evtest` on all of them to verify), so if the `XF86Forward` happens to come from a different device than the actual keypresses, ignoring that device would be an easy fix.

It turned out that there were indeed two devices.

Next step is to use `evtest --grab` on the key+mouse device to make events exclusively go to evtest, so they are not handled by X or the VT's. With VT's, this may be a bit tricky, because I don't know if switching VT's will keep the grab or not. Also have a look at `/dev/input/by-*` to identify the devices correctly across boots. If this works, you can try to launch an

```
evtest --grab /dev/input/... > /dev/null
```

or similar during boot.

That it's not an option, as the mouse which apparently part of the keyboard (or uses the same RF channel?) is also needed.

If this were for X only, one could try to use the "mouse" input device only as mouse and not as keyboard. But as you want to use the VT's, too, this is not an option.

So the only thing that remains is to write a custom filter that removes the `XF86Forward` events, while letting the mouse events through. And there was a question not long ago where I briefly [described](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656352/193028) how to do that. You'll still need to be able to write a program in a language that has a library for `uinput`.

Comment: The mouse is not part of the keyboard. It only uses the same RF channel to communicate with the USB mini-receiver.

Comment: Found the `uinput` python module you mentioned [there on GitHub](https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/python-uinput) but it does not seem to be trivial to write a filter that removes `XF86Forward` events. Hope when I have some time, I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. God bless you !

Comment: It's not hard to write - start with a program that opens another input device, and just forwards all events. Then add the filter. About one hour if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I wish I knew :) To forward all events, do I need to loop through all events and then use the `emit` method from the `Device` class in [src/__init__.py](https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/python-uinput/blob/master/src/__init__.py) ?

Comment: The [python-evdev module](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io) seems to be more documented and therefore easier to use : like [this example](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-events-from-a-device) and [that](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#specifying-uinput-device-options)

Comment: You need **both** the evdev module to **read** from the existing input device, and the uninput module to **create** and **write** to a new input device.

Comment: How 'bout [this method to create a new input device](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#create-uinput-device-with-capabilities-of-another-device) ?

Comment: If uinput is now in the evdev library as well, then you can use that, too - doesn't matter which uinput library you use.